# Not Able RDP Google cloud VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am able to take rdp using android app by microsoft named **RD Client** but not using Chrome remote desktop ,neither from Remote Desktop Connection in windows.

I double checked for rdp rule its there . How Can Fix this issue .

Error : Remote Access to server is not available

[image: Error on Chrome RDP]

Comment: Check if the RDP port is opened [1] from the outside https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap

Comment: @Alessio port is opened .Is there any other way I can Test for some other problems?

Comment: From the screenshot you attached it seems that there is not connection at all with the RPD service, in order to discard Browser issue I suggest to RDP to your instance from any windows instance running the following command on the promt [ mstsc /v:<public ip> /admin ]

Comment: @Alessio By windows instance you mean to say from CMD ?

Comment: Yep,I meant windows CMD (promt)